# Is an unique composite key optimized for retreival performance?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table.  Is the unique index on email/sites_id adequate so that a query such as `SELECT * FROM users WHERE fk=123 AND email="john@example.com";` is optimized for retrieval?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `fk` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `sites_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `unique_email` (`email` ASC, `sites_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_index` (`fk` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_sites_index` (`sites_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_constraint`
    FOREIGN KEY (`fk`)
    REFERENCES `other_table` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `sites_constraint`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sites_id`)
    REFERENCES `sites` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
PACK_KEYS = 0
ROW_FORMAT = DEFAULT;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE fk = 123 AND email = 'john@example.com';
```

The optimal index in on `users(fk, email)` or `users(email, fk)`, or any index that starts with these two columns.  For retrieval performance, the difference between a unique index and a non-unique index is somewhere between nothing and negligible.

I don't happen to see that in your list of indexes, so you should probably add it.

Note:  the query can (possibly) make use of either `unique_email` or `fk_index`, but the optimal index is a composite index starting with those two columns (in either order).

Comment: Add what?  I already have `UNIQUE INDEX unique_email (email ASC, sites_id ASC),` as well as `INDEX fk_index (fk ASC),`.  Do you recommend another index?  Thanks

Comment: @user1032531 . . . Yes, I recommend another index if your goal is to optimize queries of the form in your question.